# How to annotate optional class properties correctly?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have following example class with optional `str` 'abc'.

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, abc: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
        self.a = abc

    @property
    def a(self) -> str:
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, abc: Optional[str]) -> None:
        if abc is None:
            self._a: str = "ABC"
        else:
            self._a = abc
```

'abc' is assigned to the @property `a`. The setter method tests if 'abc' is None and replaces it with a default string if so. So the return value of getter is always from type `str` and not optional anymore. But I could not find a way to annotate them correctly. I always got following mypy error:

> `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[str]", variable has type "str")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, properties with different getter and setter types have never been supported. See [this discussion](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3004)

I can suggest to use the same type or `# type: ignore`